# Django test client get returns 404 however works in shell and web browser

Tags: python, django

Can you help me, please. I am going through the Django beginners course (https://github.com/sibtc/django-beginners-guide) and can't figure out why the test cases from the examples are always returning error 404, even though works perfectly in the shell or web browser.

I'm running Python 3.5.3, Django version: 2.0.7

Code:
url.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from boards import views as boards_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', boards_views.home, name='home'),
    path('boards/<int:pk>/', boards_views.board_topics, name='board_topics'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Board
# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    boards = Board.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'boards': boards})
def board_topics(request, pk):
    board = get_object_or_404(Board, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'topics.html', {'board': board})
```

Tests.py:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.urls import resolve, reverse
from django.test.client import Client
from .views import home, board_topics
from .models import Board

# Create your tests here.
class BoardTopicsTests(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        Board.objects.create(name='Django', description='Django board.')

    def test_board_topics_view_success_status_code(self):
        url = reverse('board_topics', kwargs={'pk': 1})
        print('url = ' + str(url))
        response = self.client.get(url)
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)
```

This test is always returning 404 error, even though i can see with print statements in this test, that DB entry exists and url is correct.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the created board's primary key is 1?

```
class BoardTopicsTests(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.board = Board.objects.create(name='Django', description='Django board.')

    def test_board_topics_view_success_status_code(self):
        url = reverse('board_topics', kwargs={'pk': self.board.pk})
        response = self.client.get(url)
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)
```

Answer (score 0):

The test won't necessarily create a Board with pk=1. You shouldn't hard code any particular value; instead, save the created instance and use that.

```
def setUp(self):
    self.board = Board.objects.create(name='Django', description='Django board.')

def test_board_topics_view_success_status_code(self):
    url = reverse('board_topics', kwargs={'pk': self.board.pk})
```